# Python: Add integer value to itself in function (for iteration)

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I am new to python. Writing a scrapy spider and got into trouble when url + items per page needs to add to go to next page.

I need that the below function iterates and the **pageoffset** variable value add to itself after every iteration.
Or any suggestion.

Like in C#: pageoffset = pageoffset + len(data['filteredItems']) but not possible in python.

```
    def parse(self, response):
        data = json.loads(response.text)
        itemcount = data['resultCount']        
        for item in data['filteredItems']:
            yield{
                'Description' : item['availableColors'][0]['productCode'],
            }  
        pageoffset = len(data['filteredItems'])
        if pageoffset < itemcount:        
            yield scrapy.Request(url=response.url + pageoffset, callback=self.parse)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import json
import scrapy

def parse(self, response):
  data = json.loads(response.text)
  itemcount = data['resultCount']        
  for item in data['filteredItems']:
    yield{
      'Description' : item['availableColors'][0]['productCode'],
    }  
  pageoffset += len(data['filteredItems'])
  if pageoffset < itemcount:        
    yield scrapy.Request(url=response.url + pageoffset, callback=self.parse)
```

Just add a `+` before `= len(data['filteredItems'])`, that's conventionally how to update a variable in Python through iteration.

Comment: I am getting error 'UnboundLocalError: local variable 'pageoffset' referenced before assignment'